# Wordpress redirecting to a non existing domain

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, ftp, admin

I was editing my WordPress dashboard and I made a type in the site url.

This typo is now causing me to be redirected to a nonexistent domain whenever I try to login through the dashboard.

how can I fix this? I currently have FTP access.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you have entered the wrong domain name in the site URL and home URL.
that's why you are not able to access the website.

For this issue, there are two ways.

**1) the First Method**

Edit **wp-config.php**
It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “example.com” is the correct location of your site.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

This is not necessarily the best fix, it’s just hard-coding the values into the site itself. You won’t be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

**2) Second Method**

Edit **functions.php**
If you have access to the site via FTP, then this method will help you quickly get a site back up and running, if you changed those values incorrectly.

- FTP to the site, and get a copy of the active theme’s functions.php file. You’re going to edit it in a simple text editor and upload it back to the site.
- Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial “<?php” line:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Use your own URL instead of example.com, obviously.

- Upload the file back to your site, in the same location. FileZilla offers a handy “edit file” function to do all of the above rapidly; if you can use that, do so.
- Load the login or admin page a couple of times. The site should come back up.

Important! Do not leave this code in the functions.php file. Remove them after the site is up and running again.

Note: If your theme doesn’t have a functions.php file create a new one with a text editor. Add the <?php tag and the two lines using your own URL instead of example.com:

```
<?php
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Upload this file to your theme directory. Remove the lines or the remove the file after the site is up and running again.

For more details Here I have shared the WordPress org Support [Link](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database, you can go into PHPMyAdmin, click on `wp_options`, then search for both `home` and `site_url` (or possibly `siteurl`) and you can change your values there as well. The previous commenter's methods will also work but using `functions.php` is unnecessary and using `wp-config` is a temporary fix, in my opinion.